# My monitor shades things to the right

Tags: display

Here is a image of it just being weird with mostly text.
[image: Fuzzy text]

And then another with the lovely tswift desktop background.  You can see it happening for the icons alongside the text. Oh and I guess beside Taylor too
[image: i do so much work]
What is going on?  This problem randomly started pretty recently and I have changed nothing with my setup...

I am running windows 7 on a PC i built myself 3 months ago.  I can look up the video card if it'd help

Comment: I can't see the effect you describe, posting an actual size (or magnified) extract from those images might be better. If using a VGA cable (not HDMI or DVI digital), it might be a problem in the cable or connector, I'd try tightening/re-seating the connector or replacing the cable.

Comment: Does this happen to the whole background or just window borders and icons?

Comment: I can see if either, even by viewing the image along and zooming it to fill my entire monitor. Do you see it in the screenshot as well as on the monitor. Of course it could just be because the image data is OK and there's something wrong with your monitor / graphics hardware...

Comment: Yeah I was a fool think it was actually showing up in the screenshots..., I'll try messing with the cable and maybe switching it out for another.  It is a vga cable

Comment: i tightened it and it looks like it's happening to a lesser extent but wont go away completely